# Any counterexamples known for the Generalized Tate conjecture?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, galois-representations, motives

One can state the generalized Tate conjecture over arbitrary finitely generated fields; to this end one should just define Galois representation to be effective if the eignevalues of the actions of the corresponding Frobenius elements are algebraic integers. Yet it is stated here http://ressources.lipn.univ-paris13.fr/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1043451&loc=fromreflist
that the generalized Tate conjecture is wrong in this generality. Where can I find the corresponding counter-example?

P.S. Possibly, I misunderstood that Math Review. Anyway, my question is: what is the status of the generalized Tate conjecture for smooth projective varieties over finitely generated fields?

Comment: So, you think that it is not the "ordinary generalized" conjecture that becomes false? Possibly, this is the rignt way to read Milne's claim. Thank you!! you!!

Comment: Did you look at the work being reviewed?

Comment: Did you actually read the review? It's talking about an "extended Tate conjecture", different from what is sometimes called the generalized Tate conjecture. Nothing is known about the generalized Tate conjecture.

Comment: Please, pay attention to the P.S.

Comment: Can you please post a link that everyone can view? Or tell us the title of the article?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to this review at the moment and I don't remember the title of the article.